# Spring Boot 2 Actuator doesnt publish jvm metric

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, micrometer, spring-micrometer

I am running a Spring Boot 2 Application and added the actuator spring boot starter dependency. I enabled all web endpoints and then called:

http://localhost:8080/actuator/metrics

result is:

```
{
    "names": ["jdbc.connections.active", 
              "jdbc.connections.max", 
              "jdbc.connections.min", 
              "hikaricp.connections.idle", 
              "hikaricp.connections.pending", 
              "hikaricp.connections", 
              "hikaricp.connections.active", 
              "hikaricp.connections.creation", 
              "hikaricp.connections.max", 
              "hikaricp.connections.min", 
              "hikaricp.connections.usage", 
              "hikaricp.connections.timeout", 
              "hikaricp.connections.acquire"]
}
```

But I am missing all the JVM stats and other built-in metrics. What am I missing here? Everything I read said that these metrics should be available at all times.

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: some findings afte looking into the code. Perhaps a core dev knows something:

For some reason MeterRegistryPostProcessor wont be applied to my GraphiteMeterRegistry and thus didnt get configured. Thats what i guess from reading the (whole) code. But GraphiteMeterRegistry is definitely loaded as bean (as seen in /actuator/beans)

Comment: I've exactly the same problem running on Spring Boot v2.0.4.RELEASE.

Comment: same problem with Spring Boot 2.1.2 when enabling @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I want to share the findings with you. The problem was that a 3rd party library (Shiro) and my configuration for it. The bean loading of micrometer got mixed up which resulted in a too late initialisation of a needed PostProcessingBean which configures the MicroMeterRegistry (in my case the PrometheusMeterRegistry).

I dont know if its wise to do the configuration of the Registries via a different Bean (PostProcessor) which can lead to situations i had... the Registries should configure themselves without relying on other Beans which might get constructed too late.

Answer (score 5):

In case this ever happens to anybody else:
I had a similar issue (except it wasn't Graphite but Prometheus, and I was not using Shiro).

Basically I only had Hikari and HTTP metrics, nothing else (no JVM metrics like GC).

I banged my head on several walls before finding out the root cause: there was a Hikari auto configure post processor in Spring Boot Autoconfigure that eagerly retrieved a MeterRegistry, so all Metric beans didn't have time to initialize before.

And to my surprise, when looking at this code in Github I didn't find it. So I bumped my `spring-boot-starter-parent` version from `2.0.4.RELEASE` to `2.1.0.RELEASE` and now everything works fine. I correctly get all the metrics.

Answer (score 2):

As I expected, this problem is caused by the loading order of the beans.

I used Shiro in the project.

Shiro's verification method used MyBatis to read data from the database.

**I used @Autowired for MyBatis' Mapper file, which caused the Actuator metrics related beans to not be assembled by SpringBoot** (I don't know what the specific reason is).

**So i disabled the automatic assembly of the Mapper file by manual assembly**.

The code is as follows:

```
public class SpringContextUtil implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext)
            throws BeansException {
        SpringContextUtil.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
        return applicationContext;
    }

    public static Object getBean(String beanId) throws BeansException {
        return applicationContext.getBean(beanId);
    }
}
```

Then

```
StoreMapper userMapper = (UserMapper) SpringContextUtil.getBean("userMapper");
UserModel userModel = userMapper.findUserByName(name);
```

The problem can be solved for the time being. This is just a stopgap measure, but at the moment I have no better way.

Answer (score -1):

I have [a working sample with Spring Boot, Micrometer, and Graphite](https://github.com/izeye/sample-micrometer-spring-boot/tree/graphite) and confirmed the out-of-the-box `MeterBinder`s are working as follows:

```
{
  "names" : [ "jvm.memory.max", "process.files.max", "jvm.gc.memory.promoted", "tomcat.cache.hit", "system.load.average.1m", "tomcat.cache.access", "jvm.memory.used", "jvm.gc.max.data.size", "jvm.gc.pause", "jvm.memory.committed", "system.cpu.count", "logback.events", "tomcat.global.sent", "jvm.buffer.memory.used", "tomcat.sessions.created", "jvm.threads.daemon", "system.cpu.usage", "jvm.gc.memory.allocated", "tomcat.global.request.max", "tomcat.global.request", "tomcat.sessions.expired", "jvm.threads.live", "jvm.threads.peak", "tomcat.global.received", "process.uptime", "tomcat.sessions.rejected", "process.cpu.usage", "tomcat.threads.config.max", "jvm.classes.loaded", "jvm.classes.unloaded", "tomcat.global.error", "tomcat.sessions.active.current", "tomcat.sessions.alive.max", "jvm.gc.live.data.size", "tomcat.servlet.request.max", "tomcat.threads.current", "tomcat.servlet.request", "process.files.open", "jvm.buffer.count", "jvm.buffer.total.capacity", "tomcat.sessions.active.max", "tomcat.threads.busy", "my.counter", "process.start.time", "tomcat.servlet.error" ]
}
```

Note that the sample on the `graphite` branch, not the `master` branch.

If you could break the sample in the way you're seeing, I can take another look.